# How to use AFNetwoking 3.0 to do post method in sync way?

Tags: post, synchronization, afnetworking

I want to request webServer in sync way to wait the response,but i don‘t know how to use AFNetwoking 3.0 to implementation.

Answer (score 0):

May be AFNetworking 3.0 does't have API to support synchronization networking,I have tried using NSURLSession and NSCondition to solve it.